# openweather api to get multiple cities

Tags: r, markdown

```
  get_weather_forecaset_by_cities <- function(city_names){
 df <- data.frame("weather_data_frame" )
 for (city_name in city_names){
forecast_url <- 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast'
forecast_query <- list(q = city_name, appid = "a297d3b46d0b5a7aab6dde3512962b99", units="metric")
for(result in results) {
  city <- c(city, city_name)
  
}
}
return(df)
}
```

Need help to understand the above given code, i am specifically stuck in the line 6 of the code, in the markdown it says "# Loop the json result" (Note: json_result is a list of lists).

But my actual task is this "Complete and call get_weather_forecaset_by_cities function with a list of cities, and write the data frame into a csv file called cities_weather_forecast.csv"
Which parts should i have to fill in and how?

```
cities <- c("Seoul", "Washington, D.C.", "Paris", "Suzhou")
cities_weather_df <- get_weather_forecaset_by_cities(cities)
```

After running the next line of codes it shows this error

"Error in get_weather_forecaset_by_cities(cities): object 'json_result' not found
Traceback:

1. get_weather_forecaset_by_cities(cities)"

Comment: Since this is a homework / coursework assignment, please read [how to ask and answer homework assignments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a homework question, it's not appropriate to provide a complete answer. However, a function that receives a list of city names and obtains their 5 day weather forecasts from openweathermap.org looks like this:

```
get_weather_forecast_by_cities <- function(city_names){
     library(dplyr)
     library(tidyr)
     library(jsonlite)
     df <- NULL # initialize a data frame
     for(c in city_names){
          aForecast <- paste0("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?",
                              "q=",c,
                              "&appid=<your API KEY here>",
                              "&units=metric") 
          message(aForecast)
          aCity <- fromJSON(aForecast)
          # extract the date / time content and convert to POSIXct
          # extract the periodic weather content, note that
          # tidyr::unnest() is helpful here
          # add the city name 
          # bind the results into the output data frame, df
     }
     df # return data frame 
}
```

We replace the commented areas with code and run the function as follows:

```
   source("./examples/get_weather_forecast_by_cities.R")
   cityList <- c("Seoul","Paris","Chicago","Beijing","Suzhou")
   theData <-get_weather_forecast_by_cities(cityList)
   head(theData)
```

...and the first few rows of output:

```
> head(theData)
# A tibble: 6 × 24
  dt                   temp feels_like temp_min temp_max pressure sea_level
  <dttm>              <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <int>     <int>
1 2022-08-03 03:00:00  27.4       31.5     27.4     29.9     1011      1011
2 2022-08-03 06:00:00  29.4       34.2     29.4     31.0     1010      1010
3 2022-08-03 09:00:00  29.2       33.2     29.2     29.2     1009      1009
4 2022-08-03 12:00:00  26.9       29.9     26.9     26.9     1010      1010
5 2022-08-03 15:00:00  25.7       26.7     25.7     25.7     1010      1010
6 2022-08-03 18:00:00  25.0       26.1     25.0     25.0     1010      1010
# … with 17 more variables: grnd_level <int>, humidity <int>, temp_kf <dbl>,
#   id <int>, main <chr>, description <chr>, icon <chr>, all <int>, speed <dbl>,
#   deg <int>, gust <dbl>, visibility <int>, pop <dbl>, `3h` <dbl>, pod <chr>,
#   dt_txt <chr>, city <chr>
>
```

At this point we have a data frame that can be easily written to csv with `write.csv()` which is left as an exercise for the reader.